# Array modifier with variable offset

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I want to apply an Array Modifier using a function based on the counter number. For example, `X Displace = Count**2`, I tried to use `modifiers["Array"].constant_offset_displace[0] = modifiers["Array"].count**2`, but the result is the count value squared, like the print:

[image]

I was expecting for *Instance 01* of the Array Modifier to result to $x=1**2 (=1)$, for *Instance 02* to $x=2**2 (=4)$, for *Instance 03* to $x=3**2 (=9)$, and so on... The graphic result is a curve, not a constant like what happens on the print.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can do that with an array. What you can do, is create "real" copies of the object and set their coordinates to the values you want.

Comment: In python ** means exponent. So count**2 is count squared. For multiplication it is count*2. Is this what you want? Or am I understanding wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a variable offset using the Array modifier, but you can use Geometry Nodes to do it.

Here's a tree that will achieve the result of squaring the distance between instances depending on the instance index.

[image]

The instance locations in the Spreadsheet editor :

[image]

[image]